# How to remove 4 byte characters?

Tags: c#, .net, utf-8, character-encoding, character

I have a integration with facebook that sends me special characters(smilies and so on, for example u+1f600 that is called a grinning face). It is not possible to store this in my UTF8(not UTF8mb4) database, so how can I make the string UFT8 (not UTF8mb4) friendly?

I can´t convert my database to UTF8mb4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple regex:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]");
string str = "abcd\U0001D11Eabcd";
str = rx.Replace(str, "?"); // abcd?abcd
```

If you look http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16 you'll see that non-BMP characters are composed by two 16 bit code units, with the ranges given in the Regex.

Comment: I have seen a example that looks like this .replaceAll("[^\\u0000-\\uFFFF]", "");, it looks like it will remove more 4 byte chars then your example? Or am I wrong? How do you know that you should only use D800-BFF and DV00-DFFF?

Comment: @Banshee On `.replaceAll("[^\\u0000-\\uFFFF]", "")`: you can't do it, because in .NET non-bmp characters are `two char`s, and regex doesn't know how to merge them. So that replace wouldn't match anything. And you can even test it with the `str` I've given in the example.

Comment: @Banshee On `D800-BFF and DV00-DFFF`, it's even written in the response `If you look http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16 you'll see that non-BMP characters are composed by two 16 bit code units, with the ranges given in the Regex.`, and in the wiki: `The top ten bits (a number in the range 0..0x03FF) are added to 0xD800 to give the first 16-bit code unit or high surrogate, which will be in the range **0xD800..0xDBFF**.` and the other range is in the next row.